# How to create a machine from alpabet

Tags: turing-machines

I was working on Turing Machines,
Then I had a problem with some one.

```
a^m . a^3n . b^n
```

How to design state diagram to this machine?
Can you please help?

Comment: What have you specifically tried to solve this problem? Do you know how to build a machine that matches `a^n . b^n`? If so, how might you extend that machine to match `a^3n . b^n`?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the result of `a^n . b^n` on the internet but I couldn't make a turing machine for my question.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? What are you stuck with?

Comment: Actually I have a language which is : `L= {w| in wthe number of a’s is at least three times more than the number of b’s}` Example input: `aabaaaba` and `a` and `b` can be any order. Then, I should make a Turing machine state diagram for it. However I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no relationship between m and n, here's the strategy:

1. Verify that everything up to the first period is an `a`. If you see anything else before you get to the first period, halt-reject. Unless `m > 0` is assumed, it's alright to see a period as the first input symbol.
2. If you see no remaining `a`s from the 2nd section, verify there are no remaining `b`s in the third section and, if so, halt-accept. Otherwise, if there are `b`s remaining, halt-reject.
3. If there are `a`s remaining in the 2nd section, cross off three of the `a`s. If there are not at least three `a`s to cross off, halt-reject. If there are, then go cross off one `b`. If there are no remaining `b`s to cross off, halt-reject. If there is a `b`, go back to the 2nd section and continue with step 2 until you either halt-accept or halt-reject.

Examples:

```
aa.aaaaaa.bb => aa.xxxaaa.xb => aa.xxxxxx.xx => halt-accept
aa.aaaaa.bb => aa.xxxaa.xb => halt-reject
aa.aaaaaa.bbb => aa.xxxaaa.xbb => aa.xxxxxx.xxb => halt-reject
aa.aaaaaa.b => aa.xxxaaa.x => aa.xxxxxx.x => halt-reject
ba.aaaaaa.bb => halt-reject
```

The states might look something like this:

```
state    tape    state'    tape'    direction    comment

q0       a       q0        a        right        read a's until you see
q0       .       q1        .        right        a period, crash otherwise

q1       a       q2        x        right        if you see a's, cross off
q1       x       q1        x        right        the 1st of 3. skip x's and
q1       .       q8        .        right        if you see . check for no b's

q2       a       q3        x        right        read the 2nd of 3 a's

q3       a       q4        x        right        read the 3rd of 3 a's

q4       a       q4        a        right        skip over any remaining a's
q4       .       q5        .        right        to get to the 2nd .

q5       b       q6        x        left         cross off one b for the 3 a's
q5       x       q5        x        right        skip over any x's

q6       x       q6        x        left         skip over any x's and
q6       .       q7        .        left         go back to 2nd .

q7       a       q7        a        left         skip over any a's and go
q7       x       q1        x        right        back to last x in 2nd section

q8       x       q8        x        right        skip over any x's in 3rd part
q8       #       halt-acc  #        same         if no more b's then #a = 3*#b
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your answer. I want to ask you something. Is this answer related with the language of `L= {w| in wthe number of a’s is at least three times more than the number of b’s}` Example input: `aabaaaba`

Comment: @Daymnn No, this TM is for the language `a^m . a^3n . b^n` consisting of `m` instances of `a`, followed by a period, followed by `3n` instances of `a`, followed by a period, followed by `n` instances of `a`. That is a different language from the one proposed in your comments. The good news is that if you understand the solution for the language `a^m . a^3n . b^n` then you should have what you need to write down a TM for `L= {w| in wthe number of a’s is at least three times more than the number of b’s}`. The idea is the same: cross of three `a`s at a time, then one `b`, and at the end,

Comment: make sure you have some `a`s left over after all the `b`s are crossed off

Comment: Actually I didn't understand because I was working 20 hours I need the `L= {w| in w the number of a’s is at least three times more than the number of b’s}` 's TM before 1 hour but at least you helped me and your occupation is very much. Your answer is true but if you have a time and give the result of the `L= {w| in w the number of a’s is at least three times more than the number of b’s}` . It is better. If you have no time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also, I will try to understand your answer. Your effort didn't for nothing.

Comment: @Daymnn I'd recommend asking a separate question for that. You can post the link to it in comments here and I'll take a look. It would actually be a little simpler than this language most likely.

Comment: Thank you I asked in a new topic. Here is the link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555870/designing-turning-machine)

Comment: @Daymnn Your other question was closed for some reason, so I have answered your question in another answer on this question. Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since your other question was closed, here's an answer for it.

Here's our strategy:

Try to cross off three a's. If we succeed, cross off one b, and then repeat the process. If we fail in either of the above, make sure there are no more b's - if not, halt-accept, otherwise, halt-reject.

Examples:

```
aabaaaba => xxbxaaba => xxxxaaba => xxxxxxbx => xxxxxxxx => halt-accept
aa => xx => halt-accept
aaa => xxx => halt-accept
```

The states might look like this:

```
state    tape    state'    tape'    direction    comments

q0       a       q1        x        right        read the 1st of 3 a's
q0       b       q0        b        right        skip any b's
q0       x       q0        x        right        skip any crossed-off
q0       #       q6        #        left         if no a's make sure no b's

q1       a       q2        x        right        read the 2nd of 3 a's
q1       b       q1        b        right        skip any b's
q1       x       q1        x        right        skip any crossed-off
q1       #       q6        #        left         if just one a make sure no b's

q2       a       q3        x        left         read the 3rd of 3 a's
q2       b       q2        b        right        skip any b's
q2       x       q2        x        right        skip any crossed-off
q2       #       q6        #        left         if just two a's make sure no b's

q3       a       q3        a        left         rewind to the front of the
q3       b       q3        b        left         tape, skipping all a's, b's
q3       x       q3        x        left         and x's until we get to the
q3       #       q4        #        right        blank at the front

q4       a       q4        a        right        skip any a's
q4       b       q5        x        left         cross off one b
q4       x       q4        x        right        skip any x's
q4       #       halt-acc  #        same         accept if no more b's found

q5       a       q5        a        left         rewind the tape, skipping any
q5       b       q5        b        left         a's, b's and x's until we get
q5       x       q5        x        left         to the blank at the front of
q5       #       q0        #        right        the tape; then repeat from q0

q6       a       q6        a        left         just verify no more b's on
q6       b       halt-rej  b        same         the tape; we're starting at
q6       x       q6        x        left         the end so scan backwards
q6       #       halt-acc  #        same
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick it is really what I was looking for.